# is there a way to delete the oldest file in a directory? using c#

Tags: c#

So i have a directory on my local laptop. Where my program stores xml documents. But i want the program to be able to find the oldest and delete that if there are more that 100 documents in the directory. 
 this is the way i check the amount of xml documents in the directory.

```
private int CheckAmountOfFiles()
    {
        var fileCount = (from file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments), "*.xml", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly) select file).Count();
        return fileCount;
    }
```

I dont know if this i possible? hope one of you can give me a hand.

Comment: Take a look at the FileInfo class to access FileInfo.LastWriteTime to figure out which file is the oldest.

Comment: We aren't going to write your code for you. You need to show us your research and the code you are currently using to delete the oldest item.

Comment: Note, that there´re *two* dates: *creation* and the *last update* one

Comment: By *creation* date, or *modification* date?

Comment: @BobDalgleish I am new with C# file management. So i dont know how to do this. I was hoping to get som suggestions on how to do it. Not necessarily the solution.

Comment: @CommuSoft I was thinking of the creation date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
  var last = Directory.EnumerateFiles(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments))
    .Select(fileName => new FileInfo(fileName))
    .OrderByDescending(fileInfo => fileInfo.LastWriteTime) // or "CreationTime"
    .Skip(100) // Skip 100 newest files
    .Select(fileInfo => fileInfo.FullName);
```

...

```
  foreach (var fileName in last)
    File.Delete(fileName);
```

Note, that in order to get required time you have to use `FileInfo` class

Answer (score 3):

First order the retreived list by the creation date, skip the first 100 elements and take all remaining into a list. Then delete all files from that list.

```
var oldFiles = Directory.EnumerateFiles(/*...*/)
                        .Select(i => new FileInfo(i))
                        .OrderByDescending(i => i.DateCreated)
                        .Skip(100);

foreach(var file in oldFiles)
{
    file.Delete();
}
```

Comment: probably, `Take(100)`, not `Skip(100)`

Comment: @DmitryBychenko where did your answer go? it worked.

Comment: @DmitryBychenko no `Skip` because the first 100 are the newest one and the question was to delete 101st and onwards